# Returning distinct rows using WHERE Exists(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE)

Tags: sql, sqlite, distinct

I've got two tables in my SQLite database with a one to many relationship between them:

```
CREATE TABLE Reads (
    RowID     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    EventDate INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Plate     TEXT,
    State     TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE ExplodedPlates (
    Plate     TEXT,
    RowID     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (RowID, Plate)
) WITHOUT RowId;
```

The Reads table's Plate column contains license plates.  The data may contain what we call "ambiguous license plates".  For example, a plate may contain "A[0OQ]C1234", where the actual second character could be a "0", an "O", or a "Q".  In this case, there are three rows in the ExplodedPlates table with the same RowID but the Plate is "A0C123", another with "AOC1234", and a third with "AQC123".

I need to join these tables and return one row for each unique RowID where the plate matches a pattern similar to the one in the example.  So if the user enters "A[O0]1234" in the search box, they should get one row with the plate "A[0OQ]1234", but not 3, as well as any rows with other RowIDs that match that string.

I've written a query using Entity Framework similar to this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.*
FROM ExplodedPlates A x
JOIN Reads AS r ON r.RowId = x.RowID
WHERE x.Plate GLOB @Plate
```

This works, but the query returned uses a temporary B-Tree to do the DISTINCT.  My boss wants me to get rid of the DISTINCT and use `WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ExplodedPlates WHERE Plate GLOB @Plate)`, but I don't know how to get this to work.  I have a specific case in my database with 135 rows that match a particular pattern, but the query I'm using returns 6557 rows.  Clearly, this is wrong.

How exactly can I use that `WHERE` clause to generate the unique list of matching reads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you want:

```
select r.*
from reads r
where exists (select 1
              from ExplodedPlates x
              where r.RowId = x.RowID and
                    x.Plate GLOB @Plate
             );
```